# Internal server error with meteor application deployed with Modulus

Tags: meteor, modulus.io

I am receiving an 'internal server error' after deploying to Modulus.io

Logs:

```
/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:423
              throw err
                    ^
MongoError: auth fails
    at Object.toError (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:110:11)
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/auth/mongodb_cr.js:39:33
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1806:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:442:41)
    at /mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:485:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:443:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:191:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
[2013-12-29T18:29:34.978Z] Application CRASH detected. Exit code 8.
[2013-12-29T18:29:36.286Z] Application restarted.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your mongodb `MONGO_URL`? the error `auth fails` means that the authentication details you've used may be incorrect.

Make sure you use something like `MONGO_URL=mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<ip_address>:<port>/<database name>` in the environmental variables with the correct username and password. You could test locally first to see your database works.